# Win2D Keystone Correction

Tags: c#, win2d

I'm trying to use Win2D/C# to project an image using a overhead projector and I need to use a Win2D effect to do Keystone Correction (pre-warp the image) as the final step.

Basically I'm drawing a rectangle, then trying to use a Transform3DEffect to warp it before rendering. I can't figure out what Matrix transformation combination to use to get it to work. Doing a full camera projection seems like overkill since I only need warping in one direction (see image below). What transforms should I use?

[image]

Comment: The main problem is, that the Transform3DEffect will not add perspective. So I think you can't do it this way. (Just my thought on this, I don't have time to investigate further... atm). One more thought: You may be able to solve this with a displacement map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an Image like following, can get you a similar effect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QnEm.png

[image]

I am unsure what results in the "bending".

Code for creating the displacement map (with GDI+, because you can set pixels fast).
The LockBitmap you can find [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp)

```
static void DrawDisplacement(int width, int height, LockBitmap lbmp)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                int roff = (int)((((width >> 1) - x) / (float)(width >> 1)) * ((height - y) / (float)height) * 127);
                int goff = 0;

                lbmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(127 - roff, 127 - goff, 0));
            }
    }
```

Drawing in Win2D looks something like this, where displacementImage is the loaded file and offscreen, is a 'CanvasRenderTarget' on which I drew the grid.

```
//Scaling for fitting the image to the content
ICanvasImage scaledDisplacement = new Transform2DEffect
{
    BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
    Source = displacementImage,
    TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateScale((float) (sender.Size.Width / displacementImage.Bounds.Width), (float) (sender.Size.Height / displacementImage.Bounds.Height)),
    Sharpness = 1f,
    BufferPrecision = CanvasBufferPrecision.Precision32Float,
    InterpolationMode = CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic,
};

//Blurring, for a better result
ICanvasImage displacement = new GaussianBlurEffect
{
    BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
    Source = scaledDisplacement,
    BufferPrecision = CanvasBufferPrecision.Precision32Float,
    BlurAmount = 2,
    Optimization = EffectOptimization.Quality,
};

ICanvasImage graphicsEffect = new DisplacementMapEffect
{
    Source = offscreen,
    Displacement = displacement,
    XChannelSelect = EffectChannelSelect.Red,
    YChannelSelect = EffectChannelSelect.Green,
    Amount = 800,//change for more or less displacement
    BufferPrecision = CanvasBufferPrecision.Precision32Float,
};
```

Comment: I think this technique would work for me with a different (simpler) displacement image. Thanks.